# Allow a service account to access google spreadsheet

Tags: python, google-api, service-accounts

I have some google spreadsheets which I want to preprocess in order to put them into an AWS S3 bucket, thanks to a python script.

To link my python script with the google API I created a project on Google Cloud Console, enabled google drive and google spreadsheet APIs for this project, and created a service account with the owner rights on this project. In order to use gspread library in my Python script and load my google sheet data. I already have the credentials JSON of the service account, but I also need to share my spreadsheet to the service account I created, but when I try the share my file with my service account, I always get the following error :

```
The policy set by the administrators of <my organization> prohibits the sharing of items with <my-service-account-mail>, because it is not a Google Account in a compatible allowlisted domain. "
```

I have already tried to add the domain of the service account to the allow-listed domains of my organisation (by the google admin console), or add a domain-wide delegation for my service account but I still can't share my spreadsheet to this service account. The only way I found is to remove every restrictions about sharing documents out of my organization but I don't want to use this because of some security issues.

Here is my Python code where the error is poping if I try to run it without sharing my file to the service account :

```
import gspread
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

gc = gspread.service_account()
sss = gc.open_by_key("<My spreadsheet ID>")
worksheet = sss.worksheet("<My sheet name>")

df = pd.DataFrame(worksheet.get_all_records())
```

And I got the following error :

```
APIError: {'code': 403, 'message': 'The caller does not have permission', 'status': 'PERMISSION_DENIED'}
```

If someone can help me with this it would really save my project please.

Comment: Can you show your python code? did you remember to delegate to the user with access to these files?   The easiest way to do this is to share the files directly with the service account.

Comment: Yes I added my Python code and the error I have in my Python code too. I have already tried to share the file directly to my service account but I have some restrictions on my organization : I can't share a file to a google account which is not in my organization domain. So i get the first error showed in my question when I try to do this. What I want is to add an exception and share my file with my service account but domain-wide delegation and adding it in the allow-listed domain don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution.
If your organization [automatically applies a classification label](https://support.google.com/a/answer/11280938?hl=en#zippy=%2Cunderstand-data-classification-settings-and-file-drive-ownership) to internally created files, that might be what is restricting external access to the file. Since allowlisting/whitelisting the domain doesn't seem to be working for you, try [removing any restrictive label from the file](https://support.google.com/a/answer/13127940?hl=en). Depending on the security settings for your organization, you may need to ask for assistance from your Google account admin or systems admin.